# Trouble Understanding Haskell Trace

Tags: haskell

How do I fix this to print out the contents of helloMsg at each nontrivial invocation of the factorial function?

```
import Debug.Trace

factorial :: Int -> Int
factorial x =
    if x <= 1 then
        1
    else do
        let helloMsg = "Hola: x = " ++ show(x)
        trace helloMsg
        x * factorial (x - 1)

main = do
    print (factorial 6)
```

As it stands, the above code doesn't compile.  I get a
 
**Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘a0 -> b0’**
error on line 9 and a
 
**Couldn't match expected type ‘a0 -> b0’ with actual type ‘Int’**
error on line 10

UPDATE: I did look at
https://wiki.haskell.org/Debugging
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html
but I didn't understand what I was doing wrong until I saw bradrn's example below.  This is a simplified example because I was having trouble applying trace to a separate unrelated command-line utility I was working on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`trace` isn’t a monadic function, so you don’t need to put it in a `do` block. Instead, `trace` takes two arguments: the first is the string to print, and the second is the result to return. So you need to do:

```hs
import Debug.Trace

factorial :: Int -> Int
factorial x =
    if x <= 1 then
        1
    else
        let helloMsg = "Hola: x = " ++ show(x)
        in trace helloMsg (x * factorial (x - 1))

main = do
    print (factorial 6)
```

(Also, you don’t need a `do` block in `main` either, since you only have one statement.)